# Stop vim from messing up my indentation on comments

Tags: vim, vi

For some reason Vim thinks all of my comments should have all indentation removed.  If I add `#` to the beginning of a line, suddenly all leading whitespace is removed.  How can I stop this?

I have Janus and NERDtree installed, in case it's relevent, along with copious other personal configurations in my `.vimrc`, but none that (as far as I know) would cause such behavior.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vim Wiki Indenting source code page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip83) and checkout how 'autoindent' works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm never satisfied with the "set all these things just in case" answers. I insist on knowing which of those things were set wrong and how they got set. Here is a command that will show you the values of all the relevant settings mentioned here, as well as where they were last set. If no `Last set from` line follows, it is a default value. No point in re-`set`ting correct default values.

```
:verbose set autoindent? smartindent? cindent? cinkeys? indentexpr?

noautoindent
nosmartindent
  cindent
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc
  cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,!^F,o,O,e
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc
  indentexpr=
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set-verbose

All I had to do to get that working was remove `set smartindent` from a plugin and add to my `~/.vim/vimrc`:

```
set cindent cinkeys-=0#
set expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a battle I fought as well, and think I finally won. The problem is that there are a dozen different ways the behavior can be overridden (by plugins/syntaxes).
Here's all the settings I had to use to win the battle:

```
set nosmartindent
set cindent
filetype plugin indent on
set cinkeys-=0#
set indentkeys-=0#
autocmd FileType * set cindent "some file types override it
```

With the `autocmd`, the first `set cindent` shouldn't be necessary, but this is one of those things where I kept adding lines until the behavior went away.

Comment: I was able to skip the last two lines and still solve the problem

Comment: @iconoclast note though that you may still have issues with some types of files. The last line is because some syntax files override indentation settings.

Answer (score 3):

ref this answer:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash

modify to:

```
set nosmartindent
set cindent
set cinkeys-=0#
set indentkeys-=0#
```

or:

```
:inoremap # X<BS>#
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem by commenting `set smartindent`.