# Disable vim from auto indenting my comment lines, but continue to autoindent everything else

Tags: vim, vimrc, indentation

I want vim to stop auto indenting any time I add a `#` to the beginning of a link after its white space.

Here is an example of the problem:

Original text:

```
dog
    cat
        moose
```

If I add a `#` comment to the "cat" line, this automatically happens (Which I dont want):
updated text:

```
dog
#cat
        moose
```

If I add a `#` comment to the "dog" line, this automatically happens (Which I dont want):
updated text:

```
            #dog
#cat
        moose
```

What I do want is the following, force vim to IGNORE any time I add a `#`, just don't indent, leave the line alone.

Original text:

```
#dog
    #cat
        moose
```

Here is my vimrc currently.

```
set number 
set nowrap 
set linebreak 
set tabstop=4 
set softtabstop=4 
set shiftwidth=4 
set shiftround 
set expandtab 
set title
set mouse=a
set hlsearch
set smarttab
set autoindent
set background=dark
filetype indent on
set filetype=html
set smartindent
set nocompatible
syn on
set splitright
```

What I have tried:
I have tried adding these settings with no success:

```
set nosmartindent 
set cindent 
set cinkeys-=0# 
set indentkeys-=0#
```

I also tried many of the suggestions in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106526/stop-vim-from-messing-up-my-indentation-on-comments) with no success.

I like vim autoindent, I want vim to use autoindent, but NOT when I use a `#` at any time. How can I force vim to ingore applying an autoindent when `#` is used?

Comment: Honestly? This is the default behaviour for C files, but not general default. What kind of file (filename extension) do you have?

Comment: `.yaml` is the problem file I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

`0#` is part of `indentkeys` in the default `yaml.vim` (some `/usr/share/vim/…/indent/yaml.vim`). On opening a `yaml` file, this will overwrite the `indentkeys` setting in your `~/.vimrc`.

My first idea is to include an `autocmd` in your `~/.vimrc` on opening `yaml` files:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.yaml set indentkeys-=0#
```